# Using UISearchController to search through an API?

Tags: ios, api, swift, search, spotify

I am currently developing an iOS application that utilizes the Spotify API to retrieve songs and play them. I am currently stuck on the search functionality.

I've successfully bridged the Spotify API (Obj-C) into my Swift project, and I've been able to create a basic search that will search/filter through an array of hardcoded data.

Now, I want to utilize the "performSearchWithQuery:queryType:session:callback:" method declared in the "SPTRequest" class but I'm not sure how I would go about doing so. I just want to search for songs and retrieve the artist name and song name.

If someone could give me some guidance as to how I would go about do so, I would highly appreciate it.

Thanks.

https://developer.spotify.com/ios-sdk-docs/Documents/Classes/SPTRequest.html#//api/name/performSearchWithQuery:queryType:session:callback:

Answer (score 1):

Use SPTSearch https://developer.spotify.com/ios-sdk-docs/Documents/Classes/SPTSearch.html

```
SPTSearch.perform(withQuery: "Some Query", queryType: .queryTypeTrack, accessToken: session.accessToken) { (error, listPage) 

        guard let listPage = listPage as? SPTListPage else { return }
        guard let tracks = listPage.items as? [SPTPartialTrack] else { return } 

        for track in tracks {
               // do something with the track
               print(track.name)
        }
}
```

make sure you add "-all_load" to Other Linker Flags or else .items will be nil every time.